# Error installing uptodate aws sdk for windows

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to update my AWSSDK for windows with one released 1 DEC to test a new Lambda with C#.
But I got error message like this.

> Product: AWS Tools for Windows -- Error 1722. 
>   There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. 
>   A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. 
>   Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Comment: You are not alone in this issue, it seems several people are having trouble since Amazon changed the way they are installing the product.  You can see a report in the link below where Amazon has acknowledged the problem but has yet to reproduce it.  --Billy

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=754278&tstart=0

Comment: I downloaded the previous build and it installed.  AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-3.3.20.0_ps-3.3.20.0_tk-1.10.0.6.msi  
That might be best until they resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report, and we apologize for the inconvenience caused.

As noted by others, for this install we changed how we install the toolkit and for some users this is causing install fails that we have not managed yet to reproduce in-house and are still trying to find root cause for.

Feel free to post your install log here (if you have it), or on the AWS forum thread posted above where we are tracking the problem and gathering data from affected users.

What version(s) of Visual Studio do you have installed, and was this an upgrade install from a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

We released version 1.11.1.4 of the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio to resolve the installation problems. You can download the latest version from https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/